# Tensorflow Slicing in loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently implementing a function in Tensorflow which randomly samples 128D vectors of a given Tensor.

So I sample n=400 Values:

```
x1 = tf.random.uniform((n,), minval=border, maxval=W-border)
```

Then I copy the values for such that i have 400 * Batch_size (B) values in the tensor:

```
x1a = x1[None,:] #(1, 400)
x1b = tf.broadcast_to(x1a,(B,n)) #(4,400)
x1 = tf.reshape(x1b, [-1]) # (1600)
```

And i repeat that step for the y coordinate, and then I apply a similar function to the Batch_size:

```
b1 = tf.range(B)
b1 = b1[:,None]
b1 = tf.broadcast_to(b1,(B,n))
b1 = tf.reshape(b1, [-1])
```

Finally I cast the tensors to int32:

```
b1 = tf.cast(b1, tf.int32)
x1 = tf.cast(x1, tf.int32)
y1 = tf.cast(y1, tf.int32)
```

Now, i want to extract these "random" 128D from my network output ((None, 512, 512, 128)) in my loss function:

```
feat1 = feat1[b1, x1, y1, :]
```

However, this throws me the following error message:

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'loss_30/ap_loss_concat_loss/Reshape_10:0' shape=(1600,) dtype=int32>
```

AFAIK, this sort of tensor slicing is possible in numpy, yet I am not sure if it is also possible in Tensorflow, my search showed that tf.gather_nd can be used for such things.

Could anybody tell me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it almost right, you just need to do:

```py
feat1 = tf.gather_nd(feat1, tf.stack([b1, x1, y1], axis=-1))
```

If you want to get the result as a tensor with shape `[B, 400, 128]`, you can reshape it after, but you can also shape the `indices` parameter of [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd):

```py
idx = tf.reshape(tf.stack([b1, x1, y1], axis=-1), [B, n, 3])
feat1 = tf.gather_nd(feat1, idx)
```

As a side comment, note that you can pass `dtype=tf.int32` to [`tf.random.uniform`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform) to directly generate integer random values.